# i can't fix : Could not find the correct Provider<AppUser> above this ProductItem Widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider, flutter-widget

here is the code :

```
StreamProvider<AppUser?>.value(
      value: AuthenticationService().user,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return MyHomePage();
      }
```

this is in the main.dart
where i add a streamProvider
to store the user id after the user login in this module

```
   class AppUser {
  final String uid;

  AppUser({required this.uid});
  }
```

after that i tried to call it in another widget

```
    final user = Provider.of<AppUser>(context);

return StreamBuilder<Product>(
    stream: DatabaseProductService(pid: pid).product,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {

      return GridTile(
        footer: GridTileBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.black54,
          title: Text(
            product.title!,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              product.favorite! ? Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border,
            ),
            onPressed: () async {
              await DatabaseProductService(pid: pid)
                  .productFavoriteState(!product.favorite!);
            },
          ),
          trailing: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.add_shopping_cart),
            onPressed: () async {
              await cart.addItem(product, user);
              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar();
              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                SnackBar(
                  content: Text('Added item to cart'),
                  duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
                  action: SnackBarAction(
                    label: 'UNDO',
                    onPressed: () async {
                      await cart.removeProduct(product.productID!, user);
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      );
    });
```

and it shows this error

````
> > flutter (17444): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════ I/flutter
> (17444): The following ProviderNotFoundException was thrown building
> ProductItem(dirty): I/flutter (17444): Error: Could not find the
> correct Provider<AppUser> above this ProductItem Widget I/flutter
> (17444):  I/flutter (17444): This happens because you used a
> `BuildContext` that does not include the provider I/flutter (17444):
> of your choice. There are a few common scenarios: I/flutter (17444): 
> I/flutter (17444): - You added a new provider in your `main.dart` and
> performed a hot-reload. I/flutter (17444):   To fix, perform a
> hot-restart. I/flutter (17444):  I/flutter (17444): - The provider you
> are trying to read is in a different route. I/flutter (17444): 
> I/flutter (17444):   Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of
> provider inside a route, then I/flutter (17444):   other routes will
> not be able to access that provider. I/flutter (17444):  I/flutter
> (17444): - You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the
> provider you are trying to read. I/flutter (17444):  I/flutter
> (17444):   Make sure that ProductItem is under your
> MultiProvider/Provider<AppUser>. I/flutter (17444):   This usually
> happens when you are creating a provider and trying to read it
> immediately. I/flutter (17444):  I/flutter (17444):   For example,
> instead of: I/flutter (17444):  I/flutter (17444):   ``` I/flutter
> (17444):   Widget build(BuildContext context) { I/flutter (17444):    
> return Provider<Example>( I/flutter (17444):       create: (_) =>
> Example(), I/flutter (17444):       // Will throw a
> ProviderNotFoundError, because `context` is associated I/flutter
> (17444):       // to the widget that is the parent of
> `Provider<Example>` I/flutter (17444):       child:
> Text(context.watch<Example>()), I/flutter (17444):     ), I/flutter
> (17444):   } I/flutter (17444):   ``` I/flutter (17444):  I/flutter
> (17444):   consider using `builder` like so: I/flutter (17444): 
> I/flutter (17444):   ``` I/flutter (17444):   Widget
> build(BuildContext context) { I/flutter (17444):     return
> Provider<Example>( I/flutter (17444):       create: (_) => Example(),
> I/flutter (17444):       // we use `builder` to obtain a new
> `BuildContext` that has access to the provider I/flutter (17444):     
> builder: (context) { I/flutter (17444):         // No longer throws
> I/flutter (17444):         return Text(context.watch<Example>()),
> I/flutter (17444):       } I/flutter (17444):     ), I/flutter
> (17444):   } I/flutter (17444):   ``` I/flutter (17444):  I/flutter
> (17444): If none of these solutions work, consider asking for help on
> StackOverflow: I/flutter (17444):
> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flutter I/flutter (17444): 
> I/flutter (17444): The relevant error-causing widget was: I/flutter
> (17444):   ProductItem I/flutter (17444):  
> file:///C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/first%20vs%20code%20project/shop_App/shop_app/lib/widgets/products_grid.dart:68:22
````

i tried like to make the user call from provider in function were i need it shows the same problem always to me that the program could not find the correct provider i can't try to use cunsumer because i gave the value to the user module from the stream provider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed this by taking all the code to another new project  and clean it also upgrade the third part dependincies
and everything is fixed